# REACT: Render JSX conditionally

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I am facing this issue when building a website that has a sidebar. I am trying to achieve a behaviour where the sidebar closes only when it is clicked on submenu items and not when clicked on the parent element. [Here is a Screenshot of how it would look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tM0zj.png). As you can see I don't want to sidebar to close when clicked on overview, finances of the state and budget.

To achieve this behaviour I am trying to conditionally render JSX in the sidebar.js file as shown in the snippet below. The buttonhook is a component that has a onClick event attached to it.

```js
{ SidebarData.map((item, index) => {
      return <span item = {item}
                    key = {index}> 
                  {item.subNav &&
                  item.subNav.map(subItem => {
              return subItem.cName ? true : false
                                            })
           ? < ButtonHook >
                  < SubMenu item = {item}
                            key = {index} />
              </ButtonHook>   
           :  < SubMenu
            item = {item}
            key = {index} />
                  }                    
         </span>
      })
  }
```

The problem with the above code is that it is wrapping the finances of the state element also in ButtonHook component. This is understandable because the item.Subnav for this element returns true. Is there any way I can avoid this and get the desired result?

The SidebarData.js has the following content.

```js
export const SidebarData = [
  {
    title: 'Overview',
    path: '/overview',
    id: 1,
    // icon: <AiIcons.AiFillHome />,
    iconClosed: <RiIcons.RiArrowDownSFill />,
    iconOpened: <RiIcons.RiArrowUpSFill />,
  },
  {
    title: 'Finances of the state',
    path: '/finances',
    id: 1,
    iconClosed: <FaIcons.FaPlusSquare size="12px"/>,
    iconOpened: <FaIcons.FaRegMinusSquare size="12px" />,
    subNav: [
      {
        title: 'Introduction',
        path: '/finances/introduction',
        id: 2,
        icon: <FaIcons.FaAngleRight />,
        cName: 'sub-nav'
      },
      {
        title: 'Major Sources',
        path: '/finances/sources',
        id: 2,
        icon: <FaIcons.FaAngleRight />,
        cName: 'sub-nav'
      },
      {
        title: 'Sources and Application of funds',
        path: '/finances/application',
        id: 2,
        icon: <FaIcons.FaAngleRight />,
        cName: 'sub-nav'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'Budget',
    id: 1,
    path: '/budget',
    icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />
  }
];
```

The submenu.js file has the below contents

```js
const SubMenu = ({ item }) => {

  const [subnav, setSubnav] = useState(false);
  const showSubnav = () => {
    return (
      setSubnav(!subnav))
  };

  return (
    <>
      <SidebarLink to={item.path} onClick={item.subNav && showSubnav}>
        <div>
          {item.icon}
          <SidebarLabel>{item.title}</SidebarLabel>
        </div>
        <div>
          {item.subNav && subnav
            ? item.iconOpened
            : item.subNav
            ? item.iconClosed
            : null}
        </div>
      </SidebarLink>
      {subnav &&
        item.subNav.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <DropdownLink to={item.path} key={index}>
                {item.icon}
                <SidebarLabel>{item.title}</SidebarLabel>
            </DropdownLink>
          );
        })}
    </>
  );
};
```

Please let me know if you want any additional information.

Comment: Maybe you could use the `Context Api` and determine in a variable if you should render the sidebar or not. Then you should alter this variable when the user clicks on the submenu item.

Comment: okay I wanted to use context api but then I thought "it's just rendering JSX conditionally, how hard could it be?" and tried doing it this way. I want to know the solution for this if possible because this kind of scenario where you have to render JSX conditionally by mapping an array of objects is not so uncommon.